# CivicRM 5.60 installation on WordPress 6.2 in Local 6.7.0 fails

Tags: wordpress, installation, civicrm

I am trying to install CivicRM for WordPress site in Local environment. I unzip the CivicRM (5.60), I place the folder into app/public/wp-content/plugins/ folder. I see the plugin in WP admin interface. I click activate, install starts, but it fails shortly after and the whole WP site becomes unusable.

PHP: 8.0.22
MySQL: 8.0.16
WP: 6.2
webserver: nginx

[wordpress after failed civicrm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XixfG.png)
[WP backend after failed civicrm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlxLg.png)

I tried to run the install a couple of times with different PHP, MySQL and webserver settings in Local, no change.

Comment: YOu may get more help if you post this to the civicrm channel https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active